# JQuery to show the file path on different input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file input and an `Apply to all` button. If I click on the button, the location in the file field should be shown on a different file field. It should be done using JQuery. Please help.

```
$("input[name='option_image[]']").each( function (){

$(this).val($("#bulk_image").val()); });
```

Comment: look at my answer - you can't assign a value to file uploader DOM element for security reasons. Otherwise it would open  possibilities to hijack your files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't apply a path to a file uploader in the browser via javascript, for security reasons.

Comment: @ Andrey is there any other option to do this?